# Apache Tika does not render td tag for blank cell in Excel file

Tags: java, apache-tika

When I parse the excel which has an empty cell, it doesn't create a extra td tag.

If there are three cells of which middle one is empty, it skips the middle cell and only outputs 1st and 3rd cell with a td tag

How can I tell tika not to ignore the empty cells ?

Thanks,
Krishna

Comment: Have you tried with the most recent version of Apache Tika? Also, do you just need to turn Excel into HTML, or a wide variety of formats?

Comment: @Gagravarr-Currently Execl and CSV file format but in further we may support PDF as well.

Comment: Do you care about missing rows, or only missing cells in rows that exist?

Comment: @Gagravarr- Missing rows is fine, but missing cells does matters to me. actually I extract first 100 rows and show it on UI, therfore in case of missing cells,value in next cell shift toward left and so on. due to this value is displayed in wrong cell.

Comment: I've [started a discussion on the Tika dev list about this](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/tika-dev/201310.mbox/%3Calpine.DEB.2.02.1310081407530.3513%40urchin.earth.li%3E), as I'm not sure if the gaps are Tika-expected behaviour or not

Comment: Thanks... Just got one old post with same issue http://markmail.org/message/thbcgyq44zuourw7#query:+page:1+mid:j4t2opcznjbhap4k+state:results